# Can Ansible be used for infrastructure inspection?

Tags: ansible, infrastructure

I was wondering if I can use Ansible for infrastructure inspection (instead of configuration) much like Chef Inspec?

Comment: There are multiple great tools for this, with Serverspec at the top and Goss, Inspec, and Testinfra right behind. Ansible is really not for this, although it can be used with them.

Comment: Do you have any quick comparison sheet for comparing them?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible will run `setup`, to collect information about the systems that it knows about. It will read data, and run scripts from `/etc/ansible/facts.d` for example, so custom data, or scripts that collect data can be retrieved above and beyond all the standard information such as memory, disks, CPU types and the like.

facter or ohai can also be used, to add to the information.